# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w)e^{-\pi \delta w^2} dw \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w) dw$ as $\delta \to 0$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w)e^{-\pi \delta w^2} dw \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w) dw$ as $\delta \to 0$. $f(w)$ is a Schwartz function. This is a part of the proof of Fourier inversion formula. The author said it is an obvious result.

I considered

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w)e^{-\pi \delta w^2} dw = \int_{|w|\le N} f(w) e^{-\pi \delta w^2} dw + \int_{|x|\ge N}f(w)e^{-\pi\delta w^2}dw$$

The $|w|\le N$ term can be dealt with by noticing that $f(w)$ is bounded on $[-N,N]$, and $e^{-\pi \delta w^2}$ is uniformly continuous on $[-N,N]\times[-1,1]$, so for given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_0$ such that $|\delta|<\delta_0$ implies

$$\left|\int_{|w|\le N}f(w) e^{-\pi\delta w^2}dw\right|\le\int_{|w|\le N} C\epsilon dw$$

But I am not very sure what's the best way to deal with the tail terms?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem#Integral_formulation

Answer (score 2):

Since $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ we have that both $x\cdot f(x)$ and $|x|^{3/2}\cdot f(x)$ belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so:

> $$ \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\left(1-e^{-\pi\delta x^2}\right)\,dx\right| \leq \|x\cdot f(x)\|_2 \cdot \sqrt{2\pi(2-\sqrt{2})\sqrt{\delta}}=\color{red}{C\cdot \delta^{1/4}} \tag{1} $$

or:

> $$ \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\left(1-e^{-\pi\delta x^2}\right)\,dx\right| \leq \||x|^{3/2}\cdot f(x)\|_2 \cdot \sqrt{\pi \delta \log 2}=\color{red}{D\cdot \delta^{1/2}} \tag{2} $$

by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the RHS of $(1)$ or $(2)$ obviously tends to zero as $\delta\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(w)e^{-π \delta w^2}\xrightarrow[\delta\to0]{}f(w) $ almost everywhere in $w$ and we have the dominating function $f$. By Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, the result follows.